# How does one disable animation in jquery-ui datepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm generally averse to animation effects given the overheads of reflow on the client side browser.

jquery-ui is an awesome widget. It has all the stuff I need. But is there a way to disable the animation -- in other words the widget just appears instead of sliding out or fading in?

Comment: Simple question ... but a goodie! Helped me out today!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

One way to achieve this (prior to jQuery UI 1.8) is to set the [`duration` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-duration) to empty string.

```
$('.date').datepicker({
    duration: ''
});
```

#### UPDATE Dec 6, 2010:

In jQuery UI 1.8+, this is a documented feature of the [`showAnim` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-showAnim).

```
$('.date').datepicker({
    showAnim: ''
});
```

Comment: Awesome! I was trying showAnim: '' and couldn't figure out why it worked in one project but not another. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using jQuery UI 1.7 for a legacy project - thanks for keeping the pre-1.8 information in your answer.

Answer (score -4):

Currently jquery datepicker plugin doesn't have any parameter to avoid animations.

Comment: Then, how do you disable it? jholloway7's response is a workaround, not a real sollution ..

Comment: @yoda It depends how you interpret the API docs to which I linked.  I interpret "speed at which the datepicker appears ... immediately" to mean "no animation".  However, I admit a more explicit API would be a welcome addition.

Comment: yes, but technically it loads the animation function, just doesn't graphically shows the animation due to the nature of the parameter passed .. Unless I am wrong